# Total Number of Reservations by Hotel Name and Month

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I'm trying to come up with an SQL Server script that shows the total number of reservations by hotel name and (check in) month. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the type of output that I'm looking for:

```
HotelName          Month     TotalReservations
==============================================
Algonquin Hotel    June      300
Algonquin Hotel    July      275
Algonquin Hotel    August    295
The Four Seasons   June      485 
The Four Seasons   July      445
The Ritz-Carlton   June      ...
```

Here's some relevant table info:

HOTEL:

```
HotelID(PK), HotelName, HotelAddress, HotelCity, HotelState, HotelPostalCode
```

RESERVATION:

```
ReservationID(PK), GuestID, RoomID(FK), CheckinDate, NumberofNights
```

ROOM (Only needed for table joins):

```
RoomID(PK), HotelID(FK)
```

Comment: So you tied to come up with something already? What have you done so far?

Comment: What if the reservation begins on June 30th and lasts 5 nights.  Is that 1 reservation in June? Or one in June and one in July?  Or is each night counted as 1 reservation; so one in June and 4 in July?  It helps to show sample data and expected output from said sample data -- and as @DavidG said -- show your efforts please.

Comment: Thanks, JiggsJedi!  As I said, for the "Month" column, I'm going by the check in date, so it shouldn't matter if the check out date month is different than the check in date month.

Comment: As @DavidG said, have you tried anything by yourself before asking SO to do it for you?

Comment: Don't you want to count Jan 2015 as different to Jan 2016?

Answer (score 0):

You could join the tables, use the [`datename`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395(v=sql.105).aspx) function to get the month's name, group by the hotel name and month and apply a `count`:

```
SELECT   h.hotelname, DATENAME('m', checkindate), COUNT(*)
FROM     hotel h
JOIN     room  r ON h.hotelid = r.hotelid
JOIN     reservation rs ON s.roomid = rs.roomid
GROUP BY h.hotelname, DATENAME('m', checkindate)
```

Comment: This breaks if the data goes over a period of a year (assuming OP counts Jan 2016 as different to Jan 2015)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select h.hotelname , 
    DATENAME(MONTH, re.checkindate) as Month, 
    count(*) as TotalReservations
from room as r 
    inner join hotel as h on r.hotelid = h.hotelid
    inner join reservation as re on r.roomid  = re.roomid
group by h.hotelname, 
    DATENAME(MONTH, re.checkindate)
```

if you have multiple years then replace this line in the query's `select` and `group by` clauses

```
CONCAT(DATENAME(MONTH, re.checkindate), ' ',  DATENAME(YEAR, re.checkindate))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    h.hotelname, 
    datename(month,res.checkindate) as month , 
    count(*) reservations 
from Hotel h 
join room rm 
    on h.hotelid=rm.hotelid
join RESERVATION res 
    on res.roomid=rm.roomid
group by h.hotelname, datename(month,res.checkindate )
```

Comment: Please add some description as to how this works as opposed to presenting it as a code dump, in order to help the questionner understand what it is doing.